# Rselenium scraping table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to extract the data in the "Completed Games" table located here "https://www.chess.com/member/magnuscarlsen".

The code below gives me a list of size 0. The Selenium side of things seems to be working. A firefox browser opens on my desktop and navigates to the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm at my wits end!

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4442L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.chess.com/member/magnuscarlsen")

Sys.sleep(5) # give the page time to fully load
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

html <- read_html(html)

signal <- html %>%
  html_nodes("table.table-component table-hover archived-games-table")
```

Comment: Given the look of the table e.g. it includes various icons conveying additional info, it would be helpful if you included what the desired output should look like. Even if only a couple of rows of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

1
If you don't mind not having the accuracy figures (for which I believe there is no published basis for calculation) have a look at the [public APIs from Chess.com](https://www.chess.com/news/view/published-data-api). You do get all the moves info included.

In particular, the implementations via [BigChess](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigchess/versions/1.9.1) package. I amended examples from there below:

All games:

```
library(rjson)
library(bigchess)

user <- "magnuscarlsen"
json_file <- paste0("https://api.chess.com/pub/player/", user,"/games/archives")
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse = ""))
result <- data.frame()
for(i in json_data$archives)
  result <- rbind(result, read.pgn(paste0(i, "/pgn")))
```

Single month:

```
library(bigchess)

df <- read.pgn("https://api.chess.com/pub/player/magnuscarlsen/games/2020/12/pgn")
print(df[df$Date == '2020.12.11'])
```

---

2. Adding in your **accuracies** as requested. Most of the info on that page is actually available via the APIs:

```r
library(bigchess)
#> Warning: package 'bigchess' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
#> Warning: package 'jsonlite' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     flatten
library(stringr)

try_again <- function(link) {  #https://blog.r-hub.io/2020/04/07/retry-wheel/
  maxtry <- 5
  try <- 1
  resp <- read_json(link)
  while (try <= maxtry && is.null(resp$data)) {
    resp <- read_json(.)
    try <- try + 1
    Sys.sleep(try * .25)
  }
  return(resp)
}

url <- "https://api.chess.com/pub/player/magnuscarlsen/games/2020/12"
result <- data.frame()
result <- read.pgn(paste0(url, "/pgn"))
#> Warning in readLines(con): incomplete final line found on 'https://
#> api.chess.com/pub/player/magnuscarlsen/games/2020/12/pgn'
#> 2021-02-15 20:29:04, successfully imported 47 games
#> 2021-02-15 20:29:04, N moves computed
#> 2021-02-15 20:29:04, extract moves done
#> 2021-02-15 20:29:04, stat moves computed
result <- filter(result, result$Date == "2020.12.11")

data <- read_json(url)
mask <- map(data$games, ~ !is.na(str_match(.x$pgn, 'UTCDate\\s\\"2020\\.12\\.11')[, 1])) %>% unlist()
games <- data$games[mask]
games <- paste0("https://www.chess.com/callback/analysis/game/live/", map(games, ~ str_match(.x$url, "\\d+")[, 1]), "/all")

df <- map_df(games, ~ {
  json_data <- try_again(.x)
  tryCatch(
    data.frame(
      Url = .x,
      WhiteAccuracy = json_data$data$analysis$CAPS$white$all,
      BlackAccuracy = json_data$data$analysis$CAPS$black$all,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ),
    error = function(e) {
      data.frame(
        Url = .x,
        WhiteAccuracy = NA_integer_,
        BlackAccuracy = NA_integer_,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
    }
  )
})

final <- cbind(result, df)
#> Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = FALSE, union = TRUE): non-time series not of the correct length
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Loving that I can use the API for this. I'm puzzled at the output of your script. If you go here: "https://www.chess.com/games/archive/magnuscarlsen" it looks like all of the games have been analyzed and should have accuracy data. For example, your script indicates that only 6 of the 24 games on December 11th 2020 between LyonBeast and Magnus were analyzed, whereas the archive page I linked to above indicates every game was analyzed. What accounts for that? Is it possible that your script is identifying only the games that Magnus himself analyzed?

Comment: I can't follow that link as it wants me to login. I will have a look at this as I can see at least one error I need to correct already. Sorry!

Comment: I have updated as I noticed filter wasn't working. Now I see 24 results of which `nrow(filter(final,is.na(final$WhiteAccuracy)))`
gives me 3 where no accuracies.

If I examine those urls with `filter(final,is.na(final$WhiteAccuracy)) %>% .$Url`
and visit their equivalents I see no accuracy figs under details tab e.g. https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/live/5941878007
versus https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/live/5941963262 (without versus with accuracy)

Comment: Interesting. When I go to chess.com/analysis/game/live/5941878007 (your first link above) I see an accuracy of 77.5 and 97.0, and when I go to chess.com/analysis/game/live/5941963262 (your second link above) I see an accuracy of 88.0 and 89.3.

Comment: Also, when you type "result <= data.frame()", that should be result = data.frame(), correct? Just want to really thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Correct. Not sure how that typo snuck in. I need to keep looking at this. I think, maybe, it is because I hijacked the callback function and that sometimes this hasn't had time to return the data (rather than the data not being there). I am finding the same thing with the website in that I can't see the accuracy and then if I click a few times on let's say `https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/live/5941878007?tab=analysis` I can then see the accuracy figures!

Comment: Ok.... so currently, whilst not fool proof, seems to work by adding a retry mechanism for cases where data hadn't loaded fully.

Comment: This is looking very promising and works perfectly when focused on magnuscarlsen. For some reason, when I simply change the username, for example to another GM whose username is "hikaru", I get an error on the df line of code. The error is "Error in read_json(.) : object '.' not found". I checked and Hikaru played multiple games on the date specified in the code, so it isn't that. Any thoughts?

Comment: I shall have to investigate though it will be tomorrow evening now I think. What date did you put in?

Comment: Tomorrow evening would be great! I didn't change the date at all.

Comment: Haven't forgotten you. So the interesting thing is that player in particular (and maybe others) has info coming via websocket rather than xhr. The data is available but basically flows under a different protocol. I need to investigate further how prevalent this is. I find it odd that the website for these player pages uses a mixture of protocols despite the content being old.

Comment: I thought for sure you had forgotten me. MagnusCarlsen is the world #1 in chess right now and has been for years - that might explain why his data flows under a different protocol (although, I can't imagine why that would matter). Interestingly, I'm still getting an error for other top 20 players. For example, using "Hikaru" as the username, who is a top 20 player, also gives that error.

Comment: Hikaru is the case I looked into. What I saw was that the request started the same as for Carlsen but then got upgraded to a websocket connection (a 2 way method of streaming data popular with gaming and sites where data needs to be "real-time".) What surprised me is that different approaches are used for data for the same time period (i.e. historic e.g. Dec'20) and pages that are presenting the same data/structure (albeit different players). It means, if you want those accuracy stats then Abhishek Arora's answer is a cleaner version.

Comment: I put in a request to Chess.Com to add the accuracy figures into the APIs themselves. In the meantime, I will have a little further look into this. I set-up a test websocket and was able to retrieve Hikaru's data but don't really want a solution that adds websockets into the equation. I'd rather an either/or solution.

Comment: Great. I saw your post on Chess.com and stated I'd like that feature as well. I don't think the API is a huge priority for them, unfortunately.

Comment: Shame. Pretty sure they just need to surface another field from a backend database table. If they can list all the moves adding a calculated figure shouldn't be that hard :-( .I really hope there isn't a master Excel spreadsheet with an algorithm doing the calculation and the last team member to know how it works having retired!

Comment: Yikes, hope that isn't the case! Any further thoughts on xhr versus websocket and the best solution to getting the accuracy figures through the API?

Comment: Currently, I would say selenium as you can reliably obtain those numbers. Feels cleaner than mixed approach. I am gonna assume they are upgrading their site and moving to websockets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that solves your problem easily because the page itself has just one table. Use rvest for easily getting it out. Note that I used pipes because I prefer them. You can of course do without them.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4443L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.chess.com/member/magnuscarlsen")

Sys.sleep(5) # give the page time to fully load
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

html <- read_html(html)

##required table
html %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Choosing this answer because I needed the accuracy numbers.